# Preserving the pitch of Tabla by keeping it in a dry cabinet

Tags: maintenance, tabla

I have purchased a dry cabinet to store my camera lenses. I also found out in its manual that you can use it to store instruments and scientific materials as well.

I wanted to know if using a dry cabinet to store a Tabla is a good idea or not.

This is how a dry cabinet just a bit bigger than the Tabla looks like.
[image: Tabla inside dry cabinet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most musical instruments are happiest when they are kept at a constant humidity of about 40 to 70% (similar to the comfort range for humans). Humidities above or below this range and rapid changes are bad. If you live somewhere where the humidity is regularly well above 70%, then a dry cabinet or a dehumidifier might be useful, but you should set it to about 70% so the instrument doesn't get a shock when you take it out.
If the humidity goes much below 40%, then a room humidifier can be useful.

Comment: I do not think the instrument will be getting a shock when it is pulled out of the dry cabinet. Humidity change effects are more subtle as compared to temperature change effects and charge change effects on materials.

Comment: Sudden temperature changes are worse, but you still want to keep the moisture content stable.

Comment: Just how dry is this dry cabinet?  Skin drumheads are not happy at very low humidity, they become brittle and can crack.  Has happened to a djembe I kept too close to the woodstove.  I'd say anything less than about 30% humidity is not good for a natural skin drumhead.

Comment: @ScottWallace The photo appears to show 45% humidity, which is okay for drum skins. It's just totally unnecessary to keep a drum in a cabinet at that humidity.

Comment: @abunickabhi I find that skin drumheads (and gut violin strings) respond quite quickly to changes in humidity (like within minutes). I would be not so much concerned that taking it out of a 45% cabinet and trying to play it in a 70% room would damage it, so much as that it would be a nuisance or impossible. As the head and tensioning straps relax it would sink in pitch and you'd be re-tuning repeatedly.

Comment: The dry cabinet can go as low as 30Rh% with the tabla inside it, and it gets upto 16Rh% when it is empty for a few hours.

Comment: @abunickabhi 30% will probably ruin your tabla.

Comment: I have set it at a constant of 45% now, since the manual it said to maintain 40-50% for musical instruments.

Comment: @abunickabhi 45% should be fine.

Comment: Okay thanks for the confirmation and the help. A lot of my doubts were cleared because of this post.

Comment: @abunickabhi You really don't need the cabinet unless your local humidity is way over 70% (and if it is, then a setting of 45% is far too low). There's no problem storing a tabla at 70% humidity.

Comment: The humidity at my place is 80-90% throughout the year.

Comment: @abunickabhi Then a setting of 70% would be good, if your cabinet can do that (as I wrote in my original answer).